# In Windbg, how do I determine if a ManualResetEvent is signaled or not?

Tags: windbg, handle

I took a memory dump of a process using

```
.dump /ma c:\mydump.dmp
```

I would like to figure out if a specific `ManualResetEvent` handle is set or waiting. I've tried

```
0:181> !handle 2db0 f Event
Handle 0000000000002db0
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  524289
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
```

I have discovered that someone got more information using the same command [somewhere on the internet](http://jumpdollar.blogspot.com/2014/09/windbg-handle-command.html).

```
  ...
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset <- this was missing when I tried
    Event is Waiting      <- this was missing when I tried
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps this is only possible when debugging a live application?

Comment: The link you refer to is a Kernel Dump while yours is a User Dump. I can't find any reference to it but I would assume that's the difference right there. You could use  livekd` from sysinternals to get a Kernel Dump and try again. *(note that navigating a KD is quit different than navigating a UD)*

Comment: The link is actually about a user mode `!handle` query. Also here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563187(v=vs.85).aspx - object specific information should be displayed as long as it's available (and it should be since the dump supposedly contains it). @brandon-cuff Is the `!handle` output really truncated at that point with just "Object specific information"? Can you check on a live application if it's the case? Also, following @lieven-keersmaekers advice - try looking at the kernel side with livekd if everything else fails.

Comment: Which version of WinDbg are you using and which OS? For me, this works on 7x64 SP1, WinDbg 6.3.9600.

Comment: I'm using win 7 x64 Windbg 6.3.9600 too

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I just did a little test locally. I took a dump of a sample app using `.dump /ma` and later opened it in windbg and it did have the information I was looking for.

In this case the dump was from a production server using the same version of windbg. However the full set of debugging tools wasn't installed; I just copied the windbg executable by itself to take the dump. (not sure if that would make a difference)

Comment: @BrandonCuff - My bad, sorry to put you on a wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

use .dump /mah not just ma handle information is not captured with /ma

```
0:012> .dump /mah c:\mydumpu.dmp
Creating c:\mydumpu.dmp - mini user dump
Dump successfully written
0:012> .opendump c:\mydumpu.dmp

Loading Dump File [c:\mydumpu.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Opened 'c:\mydumpu.dmp'
||0:0:012> !handle 0 0 event
107 handles of type Event
||0:0:012> !handle 0 f event
Handle 2c
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  4
  Name          <none>
  Object Specific Information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
```

Comment: According the documentation, `/ma` is an alias for `/mfFhut`. On my system, it works without `h` as well